# How to stop JOptionPane from choosing last case?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, case

so here is my case to make a long code short.

Let's say, we have a JOptionPane with 3 buttons.

```
boolean loopGameInterface = true;

while(loopGameInterface){

int chooseGame = JOptionePane........

   switch(chooseGame) {

   case 0:


   case 1:


   case 2:

    System.exit(0);

   }

}
```

So the problem is, when I click (example) second button, it goes to case 1. That's fine. But when the code inside case 1 is executed, it goes directly to case 2 and exit my program, instead of just looping the gameInterface?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `break;` at the end of each case. This is true for all switch statements by the way, not just when you are using a JOptionPane

Answer (score 0):

Its because you haven't added the `break` statement. If you are not adding break all the cases below the case which matches will be executed. For eg:

```
switch(ch) {
  case 1:
   /* some code without break */
  case 2:
   /* some code without break */
  case 3:
     System.exit(0);
}
```

In the above example if `ch=1` then all `case 2` will also be executed and then `case 3`.
 If `ch=2` then only `case 2` and `case 3` will be executed since `case 3` is below `case 2`. So you need to add `break` after each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(chooseGame) {

case 0: /* Your code */
        break;
case 1: /* Your code */
        break;
case 2: 
        System.exit(0);

default : "Give some default case too"

}
```